# How to use the Calendarview::setdensitycolors method from C++CX

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

Here's the method I'm trying to call:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn890067.aspx

So I create a Platform::Collections::Vector and populate it, simple enough right?

```
Platform::Collections::Vector<Windows::UI::Color>^ dayColors = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Windows::UI::Color>();
dayColors->Append(Windows::UI::Colors::Green);
myCalendarView->SetDensityColors(dayColors);
```

However, I get this compilation error I haven't been able to solve for the life of me:

error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left hand operand of type 'const Windows::UI::Color' (or there is no acceptable convertion)

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left hand operand of type 'const Windows::UI::Color' (or there is no acceptable convertion)

This error is actually thrown by code line `Platform::Collections::Vector<Windows::UI::Color>^ dayColors`. According to the Value types in Vector in [Collections (C++/CX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700103.aspx) document:

> For non-scalar value types such as Windows::Foundation::DateTime, or for custom comparisons—for example, objA->UniqueID == objB->UniqueID—you must provide a custom function object.

[Windows::UI::Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color) is struct type may contains custom comparisons so need a custom fuction object.

Add a custom struct as follows will resolve your issue:

```
struct MyEqual : public std::binary_function<const Windows::UI::Color, const Windows::UI::Color, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const Windows::UI::Color& _Left, const Windows::UI::Color& _Right) const
    {
        return _Left.A == _Right.A;
    };
};

void CCalendarView2::MainPage::CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarView^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs^ args)
{
    Platform::Collections::Vector<Windows::UI::Color, MyEqual>^ dayColors = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Windows::UI::Color,MyEqual>();
    dayColors->Append(Windows::UI::Colors::Green); 
    args->Item->SetDensityColors(dayColors);
}
```

Comment: In the case of a ComponentLibrary: IVector<Color>^ GetColors(String^ fontfamily, uint32 character)
 {
  Vector< Color,MyEqual> ^ vec = ref new Vector<Color, MyEqual>();
  return vec;
 }, what should I do, because it gives a weird error

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello, you can open a new thread to detail your issue with the code snippet. Remember to show the error detail and inner error. And maybe there are people support you.

Comment: Yes I understand, give me a minute to prepare it, thank you

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/q/42488169/4725755, I reduced the code to the minimum.